# UserError: application/json is not an accepted when running Sagemaker PipelineModel batch transform

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker, inference

I built a Sagemaker PipelineModel that consists of a SKLearn estimator and a XGB model. The lines of code used to built the PipelineModel object are as follows:

```
# tuner is a fitted HyperparameterTuner
# image_uri: the xgb image
mod = tuner.best_estimator()
xgb = Model(
    image_uri=image_uri,
    model_data=mod.model_data,
    role=role,
)

from sagemaker.model import Model
from sagemaker.pipeline import PipelineModel
import boto3
from time import gmtime, strftime


timestamp_prefix = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

scikit_learn_inferencee_model = sklearn_preprocessor.create_model()
# xgb_model = mod.create_model()

model_name = "Inference-pipeline-" + timestamp_prefix
sm_model = PipelineModel(
    name=model_name, role=role, models=[scikit_learn_inferencee_model, xgb]
)

final = sm_model.transformer(instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.m5.2xlarge", assemble_with="Line", accept="text/csv",strategy='SingleRecord',)
final.transform(batch_data,
                      split_type='Line',
                      content_type="text/csv",
                      input_filter="$[1:]",     
                      join_source="Input",
                      output_filter="$[0,-2, -1]",
                      wait=False,
                      # logs=True
                     )
```

When running the transform job I encountered an error **sagemaker_algorithm_toolkit.exceptions.UserError: application/json is not an accepted ContentType: csv, libsvm, parquet, recordio-protobuf, text/csv, text/libsvm, text/x-libsvm, application/x-parquet, application/x-recordio-protobuf**. The error occurred in the second container, which is the xgboost model, as logs on CloudWatch said everything worked just fine in the first container.

Did this error happened because the intermediate response passed from the first container(sklearn estimator) to the second container(xgb) was in application/json format? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I believe you have configured to accept CSV files but you are passing JSON to the transform function.